# Is it possible to restrict a Google Places API key by IP when it is used through JS?

Tags: javascript, google-api, api-key

I have a website with a form where the user can find their address using the Google Places API. For security reasons I would like to restrict access to my Google API Key, where it can only be used on my websites. I'm wondering if it's possible to restrict my Google Places API key by IP that I am including in JavaScript.

According to [this information by Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem), The Google Places API is a webservice API. Webservice APIs should be protected by IP address.

> You can add an application restriction to the API key. Once restricted, a key will only work on platforms that support that type of restriction. Four types of application restrictions are available. APIs enforcing the same restriction type can use the same restricted key.
>
> IP addresses (individual servers) - for use with the **web service APIs**.

However, as I am loading in the script through JavaScript the actions would be made by the user, thus sending their IP in the request to Google, meaning I would have to whitelist the user IP instead of my server IP. This is impossible for me as I have many different unknown users accessing my website.

Is there any way to restrict the API key by **my servers** IP when using JavaScript or do I have to rebuild my website where I process these calls to Google through PHP. Then I would assume Google actually sees my server IP and I can simply whitelist that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried going to google developer console and adding restrictions to the key there?

Comment: I have, whenever I try to restrict by IP it will only allow the IP of the user, which could be anywhere in the world. So sadly that doesn't seem to work as I would like it to. I get the RefererNotAllowedMapError from Google.